# CreateDirRequest - changing path manually

Tags: nsis

In my code I use `NSD_CreateDirRequest` to set path to folder. When I use browse button it work good. But when I change directory manually it doesn't work.

Ex.
I choose this directory using Browse button:

`C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder`

And when I change directory manually to:

`C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder2`

And press next, it't still old directory: `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder` 
How to fix it?

My code:

```
    ${NSD_CreateDirRequest} 0 22u 84% 12u "Choose directory"
    Pop $Dir
    ${NSD_SetText} $Dir $DirApp
    ${NSD_CreateBrowseButton} 85% 22u 15% 12u "Choose"
    Pop $BrowseButton
    ${NSD_OnClick} $BrowseButton OnBrowseForDir

Function OnBrowseForDir

    nsDialogs::SelectFolderDialog /NOUNLOAD "Directory" 
    Pop $0
    ${If} $0 == error
    ${Else}
        StrCpy $DirApp $0
        ${NSD_SetText} $Dir $DirApp
    ${EndIf}

FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read explicitely the value of the directory, for example in a page leaving callback:

```
Page custom CustomPageName LeaveCallback

# ...

Function LeaveCallback
    ${NSD_GetText} $Dir $DirApp
FunctionEnd
```